# php getting filetime not exact date

Tags: php

I have this code which I got it here in stackoverflow but my problem is when I create a file it will become January 01, 1970 08:01 AM as a date.

this is my code

```
if ($handle = opendir('backup')) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      clearstatcache();
      echo "
        <tr>
          <td>".$entry."</td>
          <td>".date('F d, Y h:m A', filemtime($entry))."</td>
        </tr>
      ";
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Which kind of file system is used (ext4, nfs, ntfs, fat, ...)? `filemtime()` most likely returns `false`. Check it with `var_dump(filemtime($entry));`. When the function fails, it logs a warning. So check the logs as well. You may have no read access for that file, or the file system may not support modification time. Better check the logs first.

Comment: the other files that I downloaded has exact and accurate date but the one that I made is not working. sorry for my bad english

Comment: So it's likely that the file system supports modification times, and you whether do not have read access  to the file, or there is another reason which can also be retrieved from the logs. On a Unix-like system, you can check the permissions with `ls -l path/to/flie` command.